# Word: how to remove an item as a field

Tags: microsoft-word

In an attempt to update all fields I have managed to add my entire document to be a field: i.e. gray with {}. I did via some combination of cmd+A then Alt+F9 or Shift+F9.

I am now stuck with 16 pages that I can't seem to get back what it was before. I do have some fields in the document which I would prefer to keep. Annoyingly, I have saved the document so can't simply undo.

[image: The end of my document]

How do I go back to the text not being inside the { } so that I can edit it and so that it prints out.

Answer (score 1):

Can you get into the field and select the text? If so, copy and past (without attributes) into a new doc.

Comment: I would prefer not too as there are also other thins in there such as tables. Surely there must be a way of undo-ing this - otherwise my disliking of word has only just deepened.

Comment: Well maybe just do a regular copy and paste then and see if that works. I agree with your disliking of Ms word it is really annoying and that's why I am going to use wordperfect until I die. It's so great

Comment: markdown and python to HTML then PDF for me

Answer (score 0):

### You apparently pressed Ctrl+F9 rather than Alt+F9 at some point.

*Neither Alt+F9 nor Shift+F9 are a part of updating fields. They are to let you see fields.*

1. You can use **Alt+F9** to display everything.
2. Then select everything between the field braces and copy.
3. Then **Ctrl+A** to delete everything.
4. Then paste.
5. Finally, **Alt+F9** to toggle back to display of field results.

Here is my [page on fields](http://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/fields.htm).